# Insert current datetime in Visual Studio Snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

Does anyone know of a way that I can insert the current date & time in a visual studio 2008 snippet?  What I want is something like this in the body of my .snippet file...

```
  <Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[
  // $DateTime$
  // more code here for my snippet...
  </Code>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no DateTime functions available for snippets but here is a macro that will insert the current DateTime:

```
Sub PrintDateTime()
    If (Not IsNothing(DTE.ActiveDocument)) Then
        Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        selection.Insert(DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

You can open your macro explorer with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> and create a new module and paste the code above inside the module that is generated.

Then create a new keyboard shortcut and bind it to your macro.

Comment: And is there any solution for C# Express?