# How to add date into C# snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, date, code-snippets

I would like to add to my c# Visual C# Express (no macros) snippet current date and time tag. How to do it? When I will use intellisense to create code with this snippet I would like to have current date and time put into code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone else asked this a few days ago: [Insert current datetime in Visual Studio Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029189/insert-current-datetime-in-visual-studio-snippet).  Looks like you can't do it, but the macro worked for me.

Comment: I've corrected my question. Thanks for link. Hope that there will a solution for Express too.

Comment: I suspect the only way will be some kind of add-in (ReSharper's Live Templates let you do this), but that's out for Visual C# Express too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Express version. It doesn't let you have add-ins?

Comment: I don't believe so.  There's a list of what's missing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions

Comment: That's a shame. I wrote an add-in that does that (dynamic timestamp) and it is a shame that it wouldn't help them.

Comment: Thanks Erich, but unfortunately Express does not support plugins

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do here. [This is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx) list of all tree functions that is supported.

Long time ago I saw simple tools that can send key strokes to the active window. Probaly this could work for you.