# In VS2005 using C#, is there a shorthand way to insert the date into the editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert current datetime in Visual Studio Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029189/insert-current-datetime-in-visual-studio-snippet)

In VS2005 using C#, is there a shorthand way to insert the date into the editor?  I want to date my comments - is there a shortcut to enter the current date?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029189/insert-current-datetime-in-visual-studio-snippet/1029205#1029205 this is only one way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in, but you can write a quick VBA macro that does that and bind a keyboard shortcut to it.